# Why can't the NuGet packages installed along with MAUI workload be found when I run a project?

Tags: nuget, maui

I installed the .Net MAUI workload from the Visual Stuido Installer and created a new project to test it. But each time I run the project, independent of the platform I am running it, I get the output -

**Failed to restore C:\Users\MBAH SAMUEL\Documents\Programming solution files\MauiAppTest\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj (in 11.5 sec).
NuGet package restore failed**

and the error message -

**Error NU1301  Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.**

The nuget packages of my dependencies in the project solution cannot be detected but when I checked, they were already installed.
Did a little research on google and it seems the packages are installed somewhere and visual studio is trying to get it elsewhere.

I tried reboot.
deleted the project I created and created a new one
no progress

Comment: From the looks of it, you are using a Windows laptop and last I checked on Windows VS bugs out if you have a space in your Solution path, here I am referring to "Programming solution" Try removing the space there

Comment: @FreakyAli thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that buh it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you get the same error still?

Comment: @FreakyAli it does

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved ticked the

> Allow format selection on first package install

in **Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General**